# phonegap filetransfer.upload to send image to server 200 bytes too short

Tags: android, cordova, file-transfer

I'm trying to send image files using phonegap's `filetransfer.upload`, but the returned file is broken and looking at logcat it the sent file seems to be 200 bytes too short.

Here is my code for sending the file

```
sendImageFile = function (imageURI, imageName) {
    writelog("Sending image file", 1);
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey="file";
            options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
            var params = new Object();
            params.value1 = "image name";
            options.params = params;
            options.chunkedMode = false;
            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            writelog("image uri length " + imageURI.length, 1);
    writelog("Image options set up successfully", 1);
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, uploadurl, win, transFail, options);
}
```

and here are some pertinent lines from logcat

```
01-07 12:27:30.743: D/FileTransfer(20066): Uploaded 114688 of 145432    bytes 

01-07 12:27:31.571: D/FileTransfer(20066): got response from    server 

01-07 12:27:31.696: D/CordovaLog(20066): Code = 200 

01-07 12:27:31.696: D/CordovaLog(20066): Response = 12099

01-07 12:27:31.696: D/CordovaLog(20066): Sent = 145236
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found. My server was accepting all the data sent as a file, as opposed to breaking it up from a form submit (i believe). This was causing there to be several lines of text just before the main image data.

To get round this I installed an old fileTransfer plugin (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/FileUploader), reverted to version 1.8.1 of phonegap (as i was unsure how to update the older plugin for the moment).

Edited the fileUpload.java file to remove all text before the file to send. Now it is readable by the server

Answer (score 1):

You can not use imageUri that you get from camera success callback on Android in FileTransfer upload method, you have to first resolve uri as a filename like this:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI){

    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function(fileObj) {

            var fileName = fileObj.fullPath;

            //now use the fileName in your upload method
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey = "file";
            options.fileName = fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            //...
        });
    });

}, errorFn, cameraParams);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is now using fileEntry.file. Looking at the communication data, the correct number of bytes are coming across but the image is still corrupted. It is fine on the device as it displays on the page once the image is taken

Comment: Maybe you have a problem on your server side code than. To be sure, use console.log on fileObj.fullPath and see what you get. If you see a correct file name (with an extension) your client side code should be ok so you might have an error on your server side.

Comment: @user1487927 that's not actually true of the FileTransfer code. I fixed it so it would resolve content: uri's to file paths in one of the Cordova releases.

Comment: All the server does is place the received file in an sql table (unedited). Upload path is correct and so is the file name, both have extension.

The sent number of bytes is still not equal to the Content length (181220 vs 181024 in my last attempt). Is there a way of sending the length over in a header (would this affect anything?)

Comment: I would try saving the file on the hard disk instead of a sql table. If you can open the file from hard disk than there is something wrong with the database.

Comment: I can't open it from the hard disk, unfortunately.

Comment: Try to update cordova/phonegap to the latest version. What is the version you are currently using?

Comment: I was using 2.2 until this morning. Upgraded it to 2.3 without any luck.